# Unable to sort results in table based on length of string

Tags: sql, oracle

This is in reference to a [hackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5). I am facing a weird problem. I am unable to sort an output of an SQL query:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LEN FROM STATION 
WHERE
LENGTH(CITY) IN (
(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION),
(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION))
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(LEN) ASC;
```

The desired output should be:

```
Amo 3 
Lee 3  
Roy 3
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

Whereas I am getting the following as output:

```
Amo 3 
Lee 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21 
Roy 3
```

Comment: Why are you using `to_number()` on something that is already a number? Remove that, and see if that makes a difference. For me, your query worked fine. You could also try getting an execution plan via dbms_plan and see if that reveals any clues as to why your ordering is not going to plan.

Comment: `TO_NUMBER(LEN)` make no sense whatsover.

Comment: Actually, looking at the link you posted, I'd be willing to bet that the issue lies with with HackerRank. It doesn't seem to pass on the order by clause.

Comment: WHY DO WE EVEN NEED TO_NUMBER(LEN) ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a column named LEN in your table?

Answer (score 1):

The code is not clean, but logically it is fine.
I can think on 2 options.

1) Not the whole query is being executed. The order by clause is left out.
2) An additional sort is being done in your execution environment.

Care to share how do you execute this code?

Comment: Please take a look

Comment: I am using HackerRank's online console for querying. Click [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5) to view the problem and the console. Details of the environment is as follows:
    **`CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production 
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
    Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production`**

Comment: @borngeek, It requires a sign-up, so I'll skip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is HackerRank environment, not your query.

if you try to run it on [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html) it works just fine.

changing `ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(LEN)` to `ORDER BY LEN` will be an optimization

Comment: Yes you can. `select dummy as my_alias from dual order by my_alias`.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to not to post any answer if you are not sure about. FYI we can use alias in the order by.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right! I was thinking about older versions of SQL Server in which you can't. but.. you posted my same answer...

Comment: not sure for Oracle but in SQL Sever you can't use the column alias in an expression in the `ORDER BY` you can only use it straight

Answer (score 0):

You are add alias to the column and sort it in the same level of the statement. You need to rewrite it like this I guess:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LEN FROM STATION 
WHERE
LENGTH(CITY) IN (
(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION),
(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION))
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ASC;
```

or you also can wrap statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LEN FROM STATION 
         WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN (
                 (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION),
                 (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION))) t
ORDER BY t.LEN ASC;
```

Comment: You can use an alias in the ORDER BY

Comment: it's depends on Oracle version

Comment: From 10g and on it should work; doesn't it work in 9?

Comment: As it appears HackerRank is using **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production** . Nothing seems to be working in my case. Sorting seems to be working on the first column only. As a matter of fact when I reversed the the order of columns it generated the rows in the desired order but the columns was not in order then.

Answer (score 0):

The question is:

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

And in the submission box there is a comment:

> Please append a semicolon ";" at the end of the query and enter your query in a single line to avoid error.

So, you have several errors:

1. Your desired output is not actually the desired output from the question (you are returning too many rows as you only want a single shortest city name and a single longest city name which are alphabetically first if there are ties on length).
2. You need to make sure the code is all on a single line (not multiple lines as you have posted here).
3. You should probably be looking at using two queries each with `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` to get the shortest and longest names respectively and then using `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) to merge them or a single query using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function.